# How to group and dispay result sun to sat, MySQL PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have MySQL table like this,

```
id  time  day

1   1:55  Mon
2   2:00  Sun
3   1:00  Mon
4   3:00  Tue
5   2:30  Sun
```

I can filter all result using this query

```
SELECT * FROM time_slots
```

but how to filter result like this output

```
Sun
-----
2:00 2:30

Mon
-------
1:00 1:55

Tue
------
3:00
```

is this possible to get result using only MySQL or should I use PHP MySQL both?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202919/mysql-dayofweek-my-week-begins-with-monday and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126961/order-by-day-of-week-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**FIELD()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function to order by on day from `Sun` to `Sat`.

Try this:

```
SELECT t.day, GROUP_CONCAT(t.time SEPARATOR ' ') AS times
FROM time_slots t
GROUP BY t.day
ORDER BY FIELD(t.day, 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'), t.time
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
  day,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`time` SEPARATOR ' ') AS times
FROM 
  time_slots
GROUP BY 
  day
ORDER BY
  `time` ASC
```

Comment: @JohnConde this is perfect but how to manage single time slot from this, i mean when i loop result, can get concatenate result, if i want to delete single time slot, it is not possible

Comment: If you want to modify the results you will either need to modify the query to use a WHERE clause that removes unwanted results or use PHP to sort and modify the results.