# MySQL order by dayname (custom formatted)

Tags: mysql, sql

The SQL I'm using  on MySQL database is

```
SELECT
        CONCAT(YEAR(EVE_DATE),'-',MONTH(EVE_DATE),'-',DAYNAME(EVE_DATE))  AS WEEKDAY_DATE,
        SUM(EVE_OCCUR)
FROM
        TABLE
    WHERE
       EVE_DATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-10-31'
    GROUP BY
            WEEKDAY_DATE 
    ORDER BY WEEKDAY_DATE
```

The output of the weekname it generates is in the format "YYYY-MON-DAY".  Currently, the output is not ordered. I would like to order it as below

```
2015-01-Sun
2015-01-Mon
2015-01-Tue
2015-01-Wed
2015-01-Thu
2015-01-Fri
2015-01-Sat
2025-02-Sun
2015-02-Mon
2015-02-Tue
2015-02-Wed
2015-02-Thu
2015-02-Fri
2015-02-Sat
and so on
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Thanks for trying @lad2025. It gets the months in order but not Sun,Mon etc. SOme improvement over the original one. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EVE_DATE column to sort the output in Query

```
SELECT
        CONCAT(YEAR(EVE_DATE),'-',MONTH(EVE_DATE),'-',DAYNAME(EVE_DATE))  AS WEEKDAY_DATE,
        SUM(EVE_OCCUR)
FROM
        TABLE
    WHERE
       EVE_DATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-10-31'
    GROUP BY
            WEEKDAY_DATE 
    ORDER BY YEAR(EVE_DATE),MONTH(EVE_DATE) ,FIELD(DAYNAME(EVE_DATE), 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY');
```

Comment: Thank you Shankar. The output is ordered by year & month. I'm still missing Sun,Mon,Tue .. Sat. The current output orders the weekday name alphabetically

Comment: @usert4jju7 Could you give me more details , we are sorting by date, ideally it should yield the output you required  , (2015-01-02 (Sun)
2015-01-03 (-Mon)), Output will be 2015-01-Sun, 2015-01-Mon

Comment: The output I get now is 2015-01-Tue,2015-01-Thu,2015-01-Fri,2015-01-Sat,2015-01-Sun,2015-01-Mon. Then the same for month 02,03 & so on. This is great. The output is ordered by year & then followed by the month. The last bit I'm missing is to additionally order it as 2015-01-Mon, 2015-01-Tue, 2015-01-Wed, 2015-01-Thu, 2015-01-Fri, 2015-01-Sat, 2015-01-Sun. Would you be able to help me with this last bit please? Just like in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126961/order-by-day-of-week-in-mysql - ORDER BY (case DAYOFWEEK(dateField) WHEN 1 THEN 8 else DAYOFWEEK(dateField) END)

Comment: I got this , you are correct, Will update the solution shortly

Comment: Perfect. I wholeheartedly appreciate your effort @Shankar. THank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can order by `EVE_DATE`:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(YEAR(EVE_DATE),'-',MONTH(EVE_DATE),'-',DAYNAME(EVE_DATE))  AS WEEKDAY_DATE,
  SUM(EVE_OCCUR)
FROM TABLE
WHERE EVE_DATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-10-31'
GROUP BY WEEKDAY_DATE 
ORDER BY EVE_DATE
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efed1/1/0)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

Example what I wanted to communicate in comment:

```
2015-01-01  - Thursday     -- 4th
2015-01-02  - Friday       -- 5th
2015-01-03  - Saturday     -- 6th
2015-01-04  - Sunday       -- 7th
2015-01-05  - Monay        -- should it be the first
2015-01-06  - Tuesday      -- 2nd
2015-01-07  - Wednesday    -- 3rd
2015-01-08  - Thurday      
2015-01-09  - Friday
2015-01-10  - Saturday
2015-01-11  - Sunday
2015-01-12  - Monday       -- 8th
```

When you sort by date you sort by actual date and not its **textual representation**.

Now you want to start from **`Monady`** but Monday does not exists in this year/month as starting point. Do you want to shuffle Monady? What you propose is nonsense for me.

Comment: @usert4jju7 See demo.I don't get your: `"It gets the months in order but not Sun,Mon "` They are ordered ascending

Comment: This definitely is better than the output I was getting earlier. What I'm missing now is the order Sun,Mon,Tue...Sat. How could I sort it in that order please?

Comment: @usert4jju7 I still don't get your point show your actual data. See that I order by date and use WEEK_DATE only as presentation. The sorting is based on dates not strings

Comment: The output I get now is 2015-01-Tue,2015-01-Thu,2015-01-Fri,2015-01-Sat,2015-01-Sun,2015-01-Mon. Then the same for month 02,03 & so on. This is great. The output is ordered by year & then followed by the month. I fully appreciate your help here. The last bit I'm missing is to additionally order it as 2015-01-Mon, 2015-01-Tue, 2015-01-Wed, 2015-01-Thu, 2015-01-Fri, 2015-01-Sat, 2015-01-Sun. Would you be able to help me with this last bit please?

Comment: Just like in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126961/order-by-day-of-week-in-mysql - ORDER BY (case DAYOFWEEK(dateField) WHEN 1 THEN 8 else DAYOFWEEK(dateField) END). Could we apply something like this to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: @usert4jju7 So it means that you don't have the data for `Monay` before Tuesday. If I understeand you correctly you want to get next Monday to move it before Tuesday, which is nonsese for me. Look at data like this `Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday` but the `Monday` belongs to **next week**. Also keep in mind that not every year/month starts with Monday

Comment: @lad2015-THe data could be in any order in the database table. Like in any other case, I've selected data & ordered it(with your query's help). If I understand the problem, it's the presence of alphabets(Mon,Tue etc) in "YYY-MM-Mon" which is causing the data to get sorted alphabetically. I've seen a few forums where similar problem is worked around just like in the example of stackoverflow I gave. See if you can help, else no problem. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using that `concat()` statement when MySQL has `date_format()`?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(eve_date, '%Y-%m-%a') as weekday_date,
       SUM(EVE_OCCUR)
FROM TABLE
WHERE eve_date >= '2015-01-01' AND eve_date < '2015-02-01'
GROUP BY WEEKDAY_DATE 
ORDER BY MIN(eve_date);
```

For the `ORDER BY`, I would recommend using an aggregation function, rather than `ORDER BY eve_date`.  This is consistent with how standard SQL works.

I also changed the date comparisons to use `>=` and `<`.  `BETWEEN` is a dangerous habit with dates, because it works differently when there is a time component.  The above method works equally well for dates and date/times.