# Mysql ninja tricks

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden Features of MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368858/hidden-features-of-mysql)

Hi,

what are your mysql ninja tricks? What features are extra special?

I'm starting with `ORDER BY FIELD` which enables you to sort in a particular order, like this:

```
SELECT url FROM customer ORDER BY FIELD(customer.priority, 1, 2, 3, 0)
```

Features like this is hard to find in the mysql documentation.

Bring it!

Comment: It would be nice if you added your trick to "Hidden Features of" question. It is seen much often and "ORDER BY FIELD" is nice feature.

Comment: +1: Not for question but for this `ORDER BY FIELD` answer. I came to this questions searching for custom ordering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Want to export a table?

Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE customer` to generate a create query.

Answer (score 2):

Use EXPLAIN to profile the query execution plan

Comment: Just to add to it -- this is an incredible tool to optimize a query

Comment: How is `EXPLAIN` unique to MySQL?